# PHP shared hosting with opcode caching (eg APC)?

Tags: php, hosting, web-hosting

Basically I'm looking for a cheap hosting solution that actually enables opcode caching. I'm having a hard time finding one. Is there a reason for this? Anyway, anyone know of one?

Answer (score 1):

Never had a chance to actually try it, but people managed to get [APC](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Pecl_APC) and [eAccelerator](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/EAccelerator) working on dreamhost shared hosting.

You've got to get your hands dirty and install/compile your own PHP, but wiki entries and dreamhost community are great.

Other good reasons to choose Dreamhost:

- real transparency; you know what, why and when servers are down. RSS feeds ad blog entries tell you what is actually going on. Even if a [fat finger is to blame](http://blog.dreamhost.com/2008/01/15/um-whoops/) :-)
- tech support is just great
- green hosting
- the administration panel is nice and you get stuff done quickly
- lots of services available (SSH, linux users, SVN repository, cron jobs...) **and** cheap

If you ever want to subscribe, look for promo codes (to get a better deal) or just ask!

**Edit:** If you want to try VPS hosting, [Dreamhost's VPS hosting plan](http://dreamhost.com/hosting-vps.html) works fine and is based on the server memory added (you can change it on the fly to save money).

Comment: This reads like a DH salesman.  The 'Transparent' blog is days behind; and never actually says what the issue is.  It's rarely accurate for unplanned ourages.  The tech support takes days to respond to obvious issues (SAN outages).  The admin panel is rather well put together; and the services are nice -- but the hosts are horribly oversold (10+ loads), and service is horrible.  Great for testing; not appropriate for anything more than a personal site.

Comment: I'm not a DM salesman :-) The shared hosting plan well... is *shared hosting* (don't expect VPS quality for sure) but is still great for what I'm doing.
Never had to wait more than a couple of hours for a tech support answer (maybe because I'm in Europe?).
Agree on one thing though, VPS hosting plan is quite expensive compared to linode. Too bad.

Answer (score 1):

Hostgator's shared plan does not allow popular php cache(like opcode caching modulus, Xcache, APC, eaccelator etc), because make customer to move to VPS or Dedicated server.

Hostgator is worst choice for website builders who hope to try PHP + Cache.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had a shared hosting package that supports any time of customization to the server, such as APC or eAccelerator.

The only way I've managed to do that is to purchase a virtual private server where I have full access.  The cheapest VPS I've had is $30/month.

Answer (score 0):

I use eAccelerator with Bluehost, I should note that I compiled it on the server with the shell account.

Answer (score 0):

I've used GoDaddy, Host Monster, and Host Gator, and none of their shared hosting accounts support APC or memcached or any other accelerator/caching module. I believe the reason is that those types of modules are CPU and memory intensive, and they can't afford to do that when 100's or 1000's of sites are hosted on a single server.

I've been using a VPS account from Infinitely Virtual for over a year now and have nginx, PHP-FPM, and APC running on CentOS 5.3 and have had no problems so far, and it only costs me $10/month. It takes some elbow grease to setup that configuration, but it's way better than using Apache and I get stable and fast response times, and that's with only 256MB RAM.

Answer (score 0):

Most shared hosting plans don't support apc, eaccelerator, etc. because they're running as apache/php-cgi for security reasons vs apache/mod_php. I'm not aware of any accelerators that work with php-cgi. A VPS is probably your best bet.